# Is there a way to inject a query directly with HibernateFilter?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to set a more complex hibernate filter, formed from multiple parameters that can be missing or not. Basically I want my filter to inject something like :

```
shipmentIds in (...) AND cityIds in (....) AND countryIds in (....)
```

In some situations is it possible that I only have the **shipmentIds** and the injected query should only be something like

```
shipmentIds in (...)
```

And because my filter needs to be rather dynamic based on what ids I can provide, I tried to do the following but it fails:

```
    @FilterDefs({
        @FilterDef(name = CUSTOM_FILTER,
                    parameters = { @ParamDef(name = CUSTOM_QUERY, type = "string")})
    })
    @Filters({
        @Filter(name = CUSTOM_FILTER, condition =  " :"+ CUSTOM_QUERY +" ")
    })
    public class MyClass { ... }
```

My filter logic:

```
org.hibernate.Filter filter = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter(CUSTOM_FILTER);
//customQuery contains the condition that I need to inject
filter.setParameter(CUSTOM_QUERY, customQuery); 
filter.validate();
```

The exception I get is this one:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying_
```

I suspect that this happens due to the **type = "string"**, used by my filter. That is using the [StringType](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/StringType.java) from hibernate which wraps my query with commas :

```
return '\'' + value + '\'';
```

So is there a way to inject such a query dynamically, or should I define multiple custom filters for each combination between the ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally manage to find a solution to this problem, so I will add an answer here.

> So is there a way to inject such a query dynamically, or should I define multiple custom filters for each combination between the ids?

The solution here is not to insert dynamically a single query since that is still not doable, but to define multiple filters, not custom ones for each combination, but just simple filters for each of them. Next we basically activate whichever of them we needed, and this way the final query will have clauses for whatever ids we can provide.

**The code looks something like this:**

```
@FilterDefs({
        @FilterDef(name = CITY_FILTER, parameters = {@ParamDef(name = CITY_IDS_PARAM, type = "long")}),
        @FilterDef(name = COUNTRY_FILTER, parameters = {@ParamDef(name = COUNTRY_IDS_PARAM, type = "long")}),
        @FilterDef(name = SHIPMENT_FILTER, parameters = {@ParamDef(name = SHIPMENT_IDS_PARAM, type = "long")})
})
@Filters({
        @Filter(name = CITY_FILTER, condition = "cityIds in(:" + CITY_IDS_PARAM + ")"),
        @Filter(name = COUNTRY_FILTER, condition = "countryIds in(:" + COUNTRY_IDS_PARAM + ")"),
        @Filter(name = SHIPMENT_FILTER, condition = "shipmentIds in(:" + SHIPMENT_IDS_PARAM + ")")
})
public class MyClass { ... }
```

**Note**: *CITY_FILTER, CITY_IDS_PARAM* etc. are just plain unique constant strings used to load the filters properly.

**Filter logic:**

```
public void applyFiltering() {
    // ... rest of the code to retrieve the set of ids
    createFilterFor(cityIds, CITY_FILTER, CITY_IDS_PARAM);
    createFilterFor(countryIds, COUNTRY_FILTER, COUNTRY_IDS_PARAM);
    createFilterFor(shipmentIds, SHIPMENT_FILTER, SHIPMENT_IDS_PARAM);
}

private void createFilterFor(final Set<Long> ids, final String filterName, final String paramName) {
    if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(ids)) {
        org.hibernate.Filter filter = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter(filterName);
        filter.setParameterList(paramName, ids);
        filter.validate();
    }
}
```

Using the above the final query can end up with additional conditions e.g.

```
shipmentIds in (...) AND cityIds in (....) AND countryIds in (....)
```

or

```
shipmentIds in (...) AND cityIds in (....)
```

or just individual ones.